# How to store, filter and retrieve JSON data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have data in JSON format. You can check the example below:

```
[
{
"firstName": John,
"lastName": Smith,
"cars": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "BMW"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mercedes"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Audi"
      }
    ]
}
{
"firstName": Adam
"lastName": Sheen,
"cars": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Ferrari"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mercedes"
      }
    ]
}
]
```

I have to store this data somehow and be able to filter it. The result should be also in JSON format because it will be used in the next step of the whole process. My ASP.NET application uses SQL SERVER (2012 and 2016).

Let's say that user wants to get all people who has a car with name 'Ferrari'. I should get result which would look like that:

```
[
{
"firstName": Adam
"lastName": Sheen,
"cars": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Ferrari"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mercedes"
      }
    ]
}
]
```

I have already spent some time for research and I know that Microsoft introduced support for storing and querying JSON format in SQL SERVER 2016 but it doesn't allow to get hierarchical result. This is relational database so the result will be "flat" as a table. Mapping JSON to tables in database is also not possible because JSON can have dynamic structure. It can be either list of people with their cars or for example bookstores with books.

I know that I could use NOSQL database like MongoDB but I would like to avoid additional databases in my project.

I would like to know best practice for such problem and how it could be done in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

**Retrieve:**

Just created and tested on this samples of data:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    userid int identity(1,1) not null,
    firstName nvarchar(50),
    lastName nvarchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE Cars (
    id int identity(1,1) not null,
    name nvarchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE CarsUsers (
    userid int not null,
    id int not null

)

ALTER TABLE Users WITH CHECK   
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_userid PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (userid)  

ALTER TABLE Cars WITH CHECK   
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_carid PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id) 

ALTER TABLE CarsUsers WITH CHECK   
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_userid_id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (userid, id)  

ALTER TABLE CarsUsers 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_userid FOREIGN KEY (userid)  
    REFERENCES Users (userid)  

ALTER TABLE CarsUsers 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_carid FOREIGN KEY (id)  
    REFERENCES Cars (id)  

INSERT INTO Users VALUES ('John', 'Smith'),('Adam','Sheen')

INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('BMW'),('Mercedes'),('Audi')

INSERT INTO CarsUsers
SELECT  userid,
        id
FROM Cars
CROSS JOIN Users
```

So I get this data in tables.

**Users**

```
userid  firstName   lastName
1       John        Smith
2       Adam        Sheen
```

**Cars**

```
id  name
1   BMW
2   Mercedes
3   Audi
```

**CarsUsers**

```
userid  id
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       2
2       3
```

Then in SQL 2016 I run this query:

```
SELECT  u.firstName,
        u.LastName,
        (SELECT c.id,
                c.name
        FROM Cars c
        INNER JOIN CarsUsers cu
            ON u.userid = cu.userid
        WHERE c.id = cu.id
        FOR JSON PATH) as cars
FROM Users u
WHERE u.userid = 1
FOR JSON PATH
```

I will get:

```
[
{
"firstName":"John",
"LastName":"Smith",
"cars":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"BMW"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Mercedes"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Audi"
    }
    ]
}
]
```

So - you can get hierarchical JSON from *flat* tables.

**Store**

Trying to load in (add little fixes in your sample).

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
{
"firstName":"John",
"lastName":"Smith",
"cars": [
      {
        "id":0,
        "name":"BMW"
      },
      {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Mercedes"
      },
      {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Audi"
      }
    ]
},
{
"firstName":"Adam",
"lastName":"Sheen",
"cars": [
      {
        "id":0,
        "name":"Ferrari"
      },
      {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Mercedes"
      }
    ]
}
]'  

SELECT  firstName,
        lastName,
        id,
        name
FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH (   
    firstName nvarchar(200) '$.firstName',  
    lastName nvarchar(200) '$.lastName',  
    cars  nvarchar(MAX)  AS JSON
)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (cars) 
            WITH (
                id int '$.id',
                name nvarchar(200) '$.name'
                )
```

Output:

```
firstName   lastName    id  name
John        Smith       0   BMW
John        Smith       1   Mercedes
John        Smith       2   Audi
Adam        Sheen       0   Ferrari
Adam        Sheen       1   Mercedes
```

This results may be inserted in the tables listed above.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The first part (where you create tables in db) is no possible in my case because JSON which I will store in db can have dynamic structure. I am not able to predict what tables will be nedded for me. Let's sum it up: JSON must be stored in DB as one record in one column.

The second part is really important to me. I did not know that I can return result in JSON format. It will help me a lot :) Could you try to modify SELECT query to return same result but when you have only one table e.g. JsonDataTable with column JsonData which contains whole JSON example.

Comment: If you will store JSON in some column and it might have unpredictable structure but you have to retrieve some filtered data - then you need some sort of parser and I bet it can be done with c# or php or whatever language much simple then with SQL.. Indeed you can transform some tables into JSON but this won't help in this scenario.

Comment: I got one idea, I could test it tomorrow and will add this to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I think that I would have to create dynamic proper Query in C# based on user custom filter which will filter my JSON and return it in JSON format.